# Change the default animation of navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am developing an app with react native in IOS. I am using the navigation to redirecting to other screens. For going forward I used the following code which contains an animation from left to right:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

For back to the previous screen I used the following code which contains an animation from right to the left.

```
  const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
    goBack();
```

My question is that, if I want to change the default animation in case number one(forward to another screen), is there any easy way to change the animation into right to left in react native (like back scenario). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
onPress={() => navigator.navigate({routeName: 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME', transitionStyle: 'inverted'}) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it says that 'routName is not defined'. I am searching on it

Comment: I have edited the answer replace YOUR_ROUTE_NAME with , the screen name where you want to navigate !

Comment: I exactly did it. But it says that routeName is not defined. I used this code: this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName: 'Home', transitionStyle: 'inverted');

Comment: Hey... you forgot {}  bracket

Comment: ({routeName: 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME', transitionStyle: 'inverted'})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178343/discussion-between-reza-and-jay-thummar).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Navigation (https://reactnavigation.org/), you can use helper methods with the stack navigator to create a transition animation.
For example, the push animation:

```
navigation.push('Profile', { owner: 'Angelina' });
```

Stack Navigation Code (full documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations):

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerMode: 'screen',
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'tomato' },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          title: 'Awesome app',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          title: 'My profile',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={Settings}
        options={{
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```